# IP based host not working on apache2

Tags: flask, apache2

I am trying to run my Python Flask backend on apache2. My conf file looks like this:

```
<virtualhost 192.168.11.11:80>
         ServerName travelhook
         WSGIDaemonProcess travelhook group=www-data threads=5   
         WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/TravelHookBE/travelhookBE.wsgi
         <directory /var/www/TravelHookBE>
            WSGIProcessGroup travelhook
            WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
            WSGIScriptReloading On
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all

         </directory>
</virtualhost>
```

But when i use 192.168.11.11:80 in my browser it doesn't work. I am running it on Ubuntu from the browser on the same machine

Comment: Needs more info: what OS? What is happening exactly? prove that 192.168.11.11 is your IP (for example, do you mean 192.168.1.11?) -- is the browser on the same machine? If not, is it the same network? Can you ping the IP from that machine? etc. etc.

Comment: Updated the question with the info.

Comment: Have you successfully run any other applications on this machine, is this the first one to have an issue, or is this the only one you've tried running?

Comment: It'd the only one I have tried running.  I am able to access the default apache server Web page.  In the logs also it says apache is running normally

Comment: 1. What exactly happens when you say "it doesn't work" -- what exact error? 2. At the command line, type: `telnet 192.168.11.11 80` -- what happens exactly? If it just sits there (no error, no prompt), type `GET / HTTP/1.0` -- what happens?

Comment: i get telnet: could not resolve 192.168.11.11:80/telnet: Name or service not known

Comment: Is apache running? Check the error logs -- looks like it didn't start.